# SquareSpace hide Image header everywhere but homepage

Tags: hide, squarespace

**ericdcreative.com**

I'm trying to have the top golden gate bridge image hidden on all pages except for the homepage.

I believe the problem is that the header isn't the header. There is left `nav bar` that I believe to be the header. I think this because when I injected code into that individual s project page (not homepage) the left `nav bar` disappeared.

```
/*hide the banner from every page */

#banner-area-wrapper { display: none; }

/*show banner on home page */
#collection-5390e8b7e4b02f5a66f7e8c8 #banner-area-wrapper { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This:


#banner-area-wrapper { display: none !important; }
#collection-5390e8b7e4b02f5a66f7e8c8 #banner-area-wrapper { display: block !important; }
```